# Web Fonts and providing fallback fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

When using `web fonts` using `@font-face` I was wondering what's the recommend method on using fallback fonts?

Like, for example if I was using a web font that was bold, such as:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansBold';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#OpenSansBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Now when you call this you obviously just do this:

```
font-family: OpenSansBold;
```

However I was wondering about providing fallback fonts such as if the download of the font fails for whatever reason.

Obviously that's easy enough to do with a normal style font (non bold/non-italic) as below..

```
font-family: OpenSansRegular, Arial;
```

However, what I'm wondering is what about when the font is bold or italic.

Is it advised to something like this and it won't affect the web font?

```
font-family: OpenSansBold, Arial;
font-weight: bold;
```

Just wondering because if you didn't specify the bold then if the web font failed, they would get Arial, but it wouldn't be bold.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are presumably using font files and a CSS file as generated by FontSquirrel. The problem with their approach is that each specific font (such as Open Sans Regular and Open Sans Bold) is represented as a separate font-family, with font weight set to normal. This means that instead of markup like `<p>foo <strong>bar</strong>` and simple CSS like `p { font-family: Open Sans, Arial }` (letting browsers default `strong` to bold font weight and select the suitable font from the Open Sans family), you will be forced to set fonts explicitly. This means setting both font family and font weight, implicitly with the `font-family` property value.

You would need to tune the CSS to get a better approach. You would use the same font family but different weights in the `@font-family` rule, and in the `font-family` rule, you would only set the family:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sans';
    src: url('opensans-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-bold-webfont.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}   
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sans';
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
* { font-family: open_sans, Arial; }
```

And then you would just use `font-weight: bold` (or HTML markup that has such an effect by default, like `strong`, `b`, `th`, `h1` through `h6`) for those elements that should appear in Open Sans Bold.

Doing it the way you describe appears to work on most browsers, too, but I wouldn’t count on it. Once you have declared a font as normal weight in your `@font-face`, setting `font-weight: bold` on text in that font could cause a) a failure, since a the weights don’t match or b) the font taken as a starting point for algorithmic bolding, resulting in double bolding. And if I’m not mistaken, b) is what happens on Safari (Win 7).

Comment: Good explanation. However, if you call them all the same name within the `font-family` how does CSS know what one to use? Wouldn't it use the last one? Additionally, any tips on how to handle stuff such as "SemiBold"?

Comment: CSS knows which one to use by matching `font-weight` set for an element and `font-weight` defined in a `@font-face` block. SemiBold normally corresponds to `font-weight: 600` for Google web fonts; the correspondences are shown in the font descriptions, such as http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

Comment: Just been testing this out and have had some issues. I set the bold `OpenSans` with `font-weight: 700;` as per the google docs, but when I load the page the text is far bolder than previously. Not sure why - any ideas?

Comment: Disregard my last comment - mistakenly set `ExtraBold` to `font-weight: 700;` as well.

Answer (score 8):

You've correctly highlighted an issue with the 'new age' of web fonts, this blog post discusses it and presents a workaround http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/font-weight-in-the-age-of-web-fonts/

Relevant snippet

> Problem number two is significantly bigger than the first. Consider FF Enzo, which doesn’t have a 400 (or even 500) weight. In some circumstances, its Light (300) weight might perhaps be a little too thin for small body type, so let’s use the 600 weight instead. Ah, that looks okay.
>
> But it’s not okay! Because if that font can’t be displayed and we fallback to something else, that fallback font will render at its 600 weight; in other words: bold.

**A workaround?**

There’s a way around this and it’s the method FontsLive use in the CSS they generate for their users: you declare each weight individually rather than the entire family. Their code looks a bit like this:

CSS code:

```
{ font-family: 'FamilyName Light', 'FallbackFamily', serif; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: 'FamilyName Medium', 'FallbackFamily', serif; font-weight: normal; }
{ font-family: 'FamilyName Bold', 'FallbackFamily', serif; font-weight: bold; }
{ font-family: 'FamilyName Black', 'FallbackFamily', serif; font-weight: bold; }
```

**Update:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansBold';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#OpenSansBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And then something like (as you suggested):

```
{ font-family: OpenSansBold, 'Arial'; font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: Great info - thanks. So in my situation, I'm a little confused at what I change.

Comment: That last snippet was EXACTLY what I needed.  Several other SO posts on the same topics did not help at all.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer works, if you want to provide a really accurate fallback font you will want to define a separate line height and letter spacing for each fallback as well. The main reason to do this is that Google recently introduced a score on Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS), indicating how much the page jumps around upon loading.

You can achieve this by putting a CSS class on the body before the font loading, that gets removed if font loading completes successfully. I do that by including this near the top of the page:

```
<script>!function(d){if (d.fonts.ready){d.body.className="loading";d.fonts.ready.then(function(){d.body.className=""})}}(document)</script>
```

You CSS would then look something like this:

```
h1,p {font-family: Open Sans, Arial}
h1.loading {font-family: Arial;line-height:16px}
p.loading {font-family: Arial;line-height:12px}
```

By adding and removing the "loading" class in the inspector you can then play with the CSS to get it to stop jumping around. With this you can reliably get the CLS to zero to please the Google gods. The only alternative alternative I've found is using a font loader library which will give a penalty on loading time.