# Reliable way to determine the width of svg text styled with @font-face

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, font-face

I'm having an issue positioning css web-font styled, svg text elements one after another using D3. When I first position the text elements on load they'll overlap.

[image: overlaping words]

However, when I position the elements moments later using the same function triggered on a delay or through a button they wont overlap.

[image: not overlapping words]

The issue appears to be with `getBBox()` and `getBoundingClientRect()` neither of which return the proper width for the element at first.

Any ideas on how to get the correct width at first?

The JS is below, an example is here: 
http://bl.ocks.org/yanofsky/6618496 
and the full code here: 
https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/6618496

```
//helper function to grab transform coordinates 
function transformCoordOf(elem) {
    var separator = elem.attr("transform").indexOf(",") > -1 ? "," : " ";
    var trans = elem.attr("transform").split(separator);
    return { x: (trans[0] ? parseFloat(trans[0].split("(")[1]) : 0), y: (trans[1] ?         parseFloat(trans[1].split(")")[0] ): 0) };
}

//position the elements based on the one before it
function positionElements() {
    txts.filter(function(d,i){return i != 0}) //filter out the first element
        .attr("transform",function(d,i){
            var prev = d3.select(txts[0][i]), //use i b/c the list shifts on filter
            prevWidth = parseFloat(prev.node().getBoundingClientRect().width)
            prevCoords = transformCoordOf(prev);

            var cur = d3.select(this),
            curWidth = parseFloat(cur.node().getBoundingClientRect().width)
            curCoords = transformCoordOf(cur);

            var y = prevCoords.y,
                x = prevCoords.x + prevWidth + 10;

            return "translate("+x+","+y+")";
        })
}

var names = ["apples","oranges","bananas"]
var canvas = d3.select("#content")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width","600px")
    .attr("height","100px");

var txts = canvas.selectAll("text").data(names)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform","translate(10,50)")
    .text(function(d){return d});

positionElements()

d3.select("button").on("click",function(){positionElements()})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried the browser load event (I also know practically nothing about web fonts), but when we ran into this issue (hacking on Chartbuilder, nonetheless), we solved it by using [WebFontLoader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) and waiting for the [active event](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#events). One wrinkle with this: the text has to appear on the page in order to ever be loaded, so you'll need a hidden span (or whatever) that uses your font.

Here's our code (we load the font from [fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com):

```
WebFont.load({
    monotype: {
        projectId: '65980087-55e2-40ca-85ae-729fca359467',
    },
    active: function(name) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            ChartBuilder.start();
        });
    }
});
```

**Addendum**: I don't think it really makes any practical difference, but we also switched to using `getComputedTextLength()` instead of measuring the bounding box, just because it seemed more correct. See [the code here](https://github.com/nprapps/Chartbuilder/blob/master/www/js/gneisschart.js#L171).

Comment: Perfect! I was worried I was going to have to write all that size change detection myself!

Comment: @bouvard have you ever had issues on Mobile? Using WebFontLoader and active event (on mobile), sometimes when I calculate the text sizes straight after assigning the new font to the element, these are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The font you're referencing hasn't been downloaded at the time you first render the `<text>` elements and measure their width.  So at this point in time you're getting a smaller width that you get later on after the referenced font has been loaded.

Waiting for the browser's load event (as [Robert suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18886472/1040479)) is something worth trying, but I'm not sure that will work on all browsers.  I read something earlier that implied that some browsers don't actually load remote @font-face fonts until they encounter a first *usage* not just the CSS declaration.  But I haven't had any experience with this so I'm not positive.

Here is a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249773/when-do-web-fonts-load-and-can-you-pre-load-them) that has a couple of good answers full of links about @font-face and download timing.