# Init loaded text with remote web font in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, fabricjs

I'm working on a big custom application with Fabric JS and I already did a great job. But I have a problem with init loaded text object that uses a webfont.

As long as that font is local on the client's computer, I works fine, ELSE the webfont is NOT loaded and the text object on the canvas is rendered in a default sans-serif font-family.

Here is, in short, what I do *(in this example I use "allstar" as my webfont)*:

**CSS:** *The css is loaded inside fonts.css in the head before fabric.js*

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'allstar';
    src:
        url('/path-to-fonts/all_star-webfont.eot');
    src:
        url('/path-to-fonts/all_star-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/path-to-fonts/all_star-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/path-to-fonts/all_star-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/path-to-fonts/all_star-webfont.svg#allstarregular') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
}
```

**Javascript:** *this is loaded at the bottom of the page inside $(document).ready(function(){})*

```
var textSample = new fabric.Text(text, {
    fontFamily: "allstar",
});
canvas.add(textSample);
canvas.renderAll();
```

If I use the font elsewhere on the page (e.g.: in a transparent span tag with a dot and the font loaded), it works fine. But I don't think that's a proper way to code.

I Use fabric.js version 1.3.0

Answer (score 4):

The issue:

1. Canvas renders immediately
2. Google loads webfonts
3. Canvas has no idea until the next event that re renders it

The solution:

1. Canvas renders immediately
2. Google loads webfonts with a callback
3. You force render
4. Canvas now has the

http://jsfiddle.net/vvL6f/6/

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Ribeye::latin', 'Lora::latin', 'Croissant+One::latin', 'Emblema+One::latin', 'Graduate::latin', 'Hammersmith+One::latin', 'Oswald::latin', 'Oxygen::latin', 'Krona+One::latin', 'Indie+Flower::latin', 'Courgette::latin', 'Ranchers::latin' ] }
};

(function() {
    var src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';

    $.getScript(src, function(data) {      
        // Not sure why I need to run this twice but it makes it load the font and then reposition the font to it's correct coords.
        canvas.renderAll();
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
})();
```

Comment: not working (Google chrome). I had to use setTimeout for re-rendering

Comment: +1 webfont loader fixes issue for me without even explicitly setting any callbacks. I just load the web fonts, then load my canvas & it works now.

Comment: That's a much better idea actually.  You could also setup something with async to load everything correctly in order. https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback

Answer (score 2):

Short way:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
WebFont.load({
            google: {
                families: [ 'Abel', 'Aclonica']
            },
            fontinactive: function(familyName, fvd) {
                console.log("Sorry " + familyName + " font family can't be loaded at the moment. Retry later.");
            },
            active: function() {
                // do some stuff with font   
                $('#stuff').attr('style', "font-family:'Abel'");
                var text = new fabric.Text("Text Here", {
                    left: 200,
                    top: 30,
                    fontFamily: 'Abel',
                    fill: '#000',
                    fontSize: 60
                });

                canvas.add(text);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Long way [When do web-fonts load and can you pre-load them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249773/when-do-web-fonts-load-and-can-you-pre-load-them)

More on web font loader https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader .

[fabric.js](/questions/tagged/fabric.js) specific https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/sV_9xanu6Bg

Answer (score 1):

Using fabric.js and Google Web Fonts, the following code works for me:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DanBrown180/vvL6f/

CSS

```
<Style>
@font-face {
font-family: 'Jolly Lodger';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: local('Jolly Lodger'), local('JollyLodger'),
url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/jollylodger/v1/RX8HnkBgaEKQSHQyP9itiaRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff) format('woff');
}
<style>
```

Javascript

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'); 
var text = new fabric.Text("Web Font Example", {
                    left: 200,
                    top: 30,
                    fontFamily: 'Jolly Lodger',
                    fill: '#000',
                    fontSize: 60
                });

canvas.add(text);
</script>
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="c" height="200px" width="400px"></canvas>
```

Looks like it's because the Google Web Fonts css code uses:

```
src: local('Jolly Lodger'), local('JollyLodger')
```

in the CSS

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for your answer, but that is simular to what I do, except you use Google Fonts. Unfortunately in my project I have to use our own fonts stored on our server. Also, if I loof into you jsfiddle example, you have the same problem. As with me, wen you click on the canvas, the text re-renders in the correct font.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Font renders correctly after some event is fired..
So after creating an object we can set it active:

```
var textSample = new fabric.Text(text, {
    fontFamily: "allstar",
});
canvas.add(textSample);
canvas.setActiveObject(textSample); // Selects the object
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method is using setTimeout();

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    activeObject.set({
        fontFamily: font,
        useNative: true
    });
canvas.renderAll();},500);
```

Check the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/muthupandiant/x3ptsgex/1/

Comment: No that is not the best method because 1) if the font takes longer than 500ms it doesn't fix the issue & 2) if the font takes less than 500ms, our app waits that long anyways & feels slow.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017, it is easily possible to use web fonts within Fabric.js in Firefox.

You only have to include them via `@import` (in your stylesheet) or via `<link href="...">` (in `<head>`). Afterwards you can select any font you want using fabric.Text's attribute 'fontFamily'.

Concerning your initial problem, calling `canvas.renderAll();` should redraw the canvas and thus display all loaded web fonts correctly.

See a [simple example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juyspg7c/1/).